# Select Loop - Dynamic Output using input file to read

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, aix

Awesome forum!! I'll try keep this short to get to the point. I've been trying to understand whether it would be possible to read in a file which has a list of details on each new line. For example:

Filename: ALIAS_LIST.config

```
ALIAS1 CLUSTER1
ALIAS2 CLUSTER2
ALIAS3 CLUSTER3
QUIT
```

Based on this I was hoping I would be able to read through the file list as an array for each new line and generate a dynamic output using the Select Loop which i've done nicely for my menu. I'm up to the part of my script which is the actual actioning of tasks. Here is an example of what I was trying to achieve:

```
# *********************************
# Sourcing the Alias Queue file to use
# *********************************

ALIAS_FILE="/var/ALIAS_LIST.config"

if [ -f "$ALIAS_FILE" ]
then
    select alias_select in "${ALIAS_FILE[@]}"
    do
      echo "well done"
    done
else
    echo "*********************************"
    echo " Exit
    echo "*********************************"

exit 0

fi
```

Based on this output from a file into an array select menu I'll use the standard PS3 to capture and verify the use input and take the necessary steps moving forward.

Based on updates this worked exactly how I expected it to. What if in turn we are trying to validate the user input to provide helpful exception handling. Here is what i'm trying to achieve based on your input:

Updated Version (working):

```
    mapfile -t arr < "/var/ALIAS_LIST.config"

    select alias_select in "${arr[@]}"
    do
    if [[ -z "$alias_select" ]]
    then
        echo
        echo "Invalid Choice"
        echo
    elif [[ $alias_select == "QUIT" ]]
    then
        break
    else
        echo
        echo "You selected: $alias_select"
        echo

        ALIAS=$(echo "${alias_select}" | awk '{print $1}')
        OPTION=$(echo "${alias_select}" | awk '{print $2}')

        echo "$ALIAS"
        echo "$OPTION"
    fi
    done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use this script to read `select` menu items from a file:

```
mapfile -t arr </var/ALIAS_LIST.config

select alias_select in "${arr[@]}"; do
   if [[ -z "$alias_select" ]]; then
      echo "Invalid Choice"
   elif [[ $alias_select == "QUIT" ]]; then
      break
   else
      echo "You selected: $alias_select"
   fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance on how to edit. I've updated as suggested in my original question. I have also marked you as a tick but can only see as a valid tick until the rep points on my end is 15. Can you please assit with the further updates i've pasted up in the original question.

Comment: done as requested. Should I raise another question for the next query or continue based on my updates?

Comment: did some more testing today and realized when you stdin the details from the file it treats every word followed by a space as a seperate menu item. What i'm trying to do is pull in data line by line rather than word by word. Is this possible?

Comment: Thank you that worked however I have a query here. Assuming we have AIX and there is only korn shell this would not work?

Comment: I have also added in some error handling however i'm having an issue where the script validates the first select option as an invalid choice! Why would the array think the first selection is incorrect. I've updated the code in the second code snippet.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve error handling. I'm trying to insure the user input selected is that of the valid selection based on the selected number input. This means if they put in a bad character or a bad number given in the menu it'll relay that back to the user saying invalid choice pick again.

Comment: however what if i wish to provide some valid response to the user. Have a look at my second snippet of code and let me know if it can be achieved or if there is a better way?

Comment: that worked perfectly. Awesome thank you very much! I have 2 questions here. If i wanted to validate a null return from the keyboard if the user hasn't selected an option to reprint them menu how could this be achieved? and if a invalid choice is made to clear the screen / reprint the menu but insure the error message is still visible? maybe capture a return code as part of the exit and based on that provide an error?

Comment: Sorry this comment section has gone too long and against the concept of SO (one problem per thread). You can create a new question and ask your new problem.

Comment: I have raised another question as requested. Thank You